# How to host Alexa Skill using Express API (Web Server)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I've been stuck with hosting an alexa skill webserver on my localhost!
Everything's correct from the Intents I've made, the url works, and it does request the intent I ask it for, but Alexa constantly keeps saying "There was a problem with the requested skill's response"

```js
const express = require("express");
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const { ExpressAdapter } = require("ask-sdk-express-adapter");
const app = express();

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = 'Hello World - Your skill has launched';

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

const builder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();
builder.addRequestHandlers(
    LaunchRequestHandler
);
const skill = builder.create();
const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(skill, false, false);

app.post('/', adapter.getRequestHandlers());
app.listen(443, null, () => {
    console.log("App is now online!");
});
```

This is the json body it gives when it tries to send a post / first

```json
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": false,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.325e7e93-3033-4e26-ada6-45f7967971bf",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.c1ed78ba-9003-4904-9376-b9a05b3a4bcc"
        },
        "attributes": {},
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AH7FLOU7DBFRWVIENTV7VT7EMQLPAGYMFU4YUTI6OSBCK6GOKXWNQ6BI3BPZPEMN2TQFXGZCO43KXB3HJNVJPBJILPEDLGIAMQK2DK3C42S5FBPCQSN6B46FMQDATFSCL42YCF25PR5CFPGHYUFIDIJHZAJRIGMZ5BGZMU7FNJB4I6KBVDF5N2WIXCIG6YMV2X4ZO3QETGA23HQ"
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "Viewports": [
            {
                "type": "APL",
                "id": "main",
                "shape": "RECTANGLE",
                "dpi": 213,
                "presentationType": "STANDARD",
                "canRotate": false,
                "configuration": {
                    "current": {
                        "mode": "HUB",
                        "video": {
                            "codecs": [
                                "H_264_42",
                                "H_264_41"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": {
                            "type": "DISCRETE",
                            "pixelWidth": 1280,
                            "pixelHeight": 800
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "Viewport": {
            "experiences": [
                {
                    "arcMinuteWidth": 346,
                    "arcMinuteHeight": 216,
                    "canRotate": false,
                    "canResize": false
                }
            ],
            "mode": "HUB",
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "pixelWidth": 1280,
            "pixelHeight": 800,
            "dpi": 213,
            "currentPixelWidth": 1280,
            "currentPixelHeight": 800,
            "touch": [
                "SINGLE"
            ],
            "video": {
                "codecs": [
                    "H_264_42",
                    "H_264_41"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Extensions": {
            "available": {
                "aplext:backstack:10": {}
            }
        },
        "System": {
            "application": {
                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.c1ed78ba-9003-4904-9376-b9a05b3a4bcc"
            },
            "user": {
                "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AH7FLOU7DBFRWVIENTV7VT7EMQLPAGYMFU4YUTI6OSBCK6GOKXWNQ6BI3BPZPEMN2TQFXGZCO43KXB3HJNVJPBJILPEDLGIAMQK2DK3C42S5FBPCQSN6B46FMQDATFSCL42YCF25PR5CFPGHYUFIDIJHZAJRIGMZ5BGZMU7FNJB4I6KBVDF5N2WIXCIG6YMV2X4ZO3QETGA23HQ"
            },
            "device": {
                "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AGZ65ZMWRSISWS4RB63ZEBKJDJPMICI5WU6SDYTU7CZKDFASRAAR7WNYRTVKYWRURCC77E2EIGXBBUTO3REKDGWMLJDN7ODAHKWJLJCTNHN3CU3LVXDMGRJJ3HIXMWRLVT6D5OFWNYXZ73J7Y6TCONRXYL2OTJHRQ7SUGQKEBBIPNVIYZ35WI",
                "supportedInterfaces": {}
            },
            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
            "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.X2fY3XTWW8zRZtwE6km2AIaSnhaAfSLKYqzgwlZrui6OyCS03Lfh1dJWHg4sZxTZqWyssV7VFWErW-gTZFUdkagtbbknuZQ3qlVQlwpZPaKhKBYC9VBDfmnGtjjDDCAAUyvB8ZIInbuxsrZ6DwYtuj5sa5_wGSfc0s2THQqP9Azklgk5UobwMN0iWsrhDSXy4guB4KaEJscD8_OLr2ZnbvWqy3tAPv3zfEsb8OmnOC7FBMHHgN-aCIRubnZNu8YA2Xtf-usOn1wVAjaIwEdlfgrOCRfFpZc3l7tfHTfX9HfLerRFh_IWQWc61DVfQZhyH4yeH5fdKUVDMels4zXlKQ"
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.e6d2bca6-4680-4367-8bb1-104e038c35ba",
        "timestamp": "2021-12-03T02:22:58Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
        }
    }
}
```

And the 2nd json body post / request when it errors:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": false,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.325e7e93-3033-4e26-ada6-45f7967971bf",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.c1ed78ba-9003-4904-9376-b9a05b3a4bcc"
        },
        "attributes": {},
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AH7FLOU7DBFRWVIENTV7VT7EMQLPAGYMFU4YUTI6OSBCK6GOKXWNQ6BI3BPZPEMN2TQFXGZCO43KXB3HJNVJPBJILPEDLGIAMQK2DK3C42S5FBPCQSN6B46FMQDATFSCL42YCF25PR5CFPGHYUFIDIJHZAJRIGMZ5BGZMU7FNJB4I6KBVDF5N2WIXCIG6YMV2X4ZO3QETGA23HQ"
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "Viewports": [
            {
                "type": "APL",
                "id": "main",
                "shape": "RECTANGLE",
                "dpi": 213,
                "presentationType": "STANDARD",
                "canRotate": false,
                "configuration": {
                    "current": {
                        "mode": "HUB",
                        "video": {
                            "codecs": [
                                "H_264_42",
                                "H_264_41"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": {
                            "type": "DISCRETE",
                            "pixelWidth": 1280,
                            "pixelHeight": 800
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "Viewport": {
            "experiences": [
                {
                    "arcMinuteWidth": 346,
                    "arcMinuteHeight": 216,
                    "canRotate": false,
                    "canResize": false
                }
            ],
            "mode": "HUB",
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "pixelWidth": 1280,
            "pixelHeight": 800,
            "dpi": 213,
            "currentPixelWidth": 1280,
            "currentPixelHeight": 800,
            "touch": [
                "SINGLE"
            ],
            "video": {
                "codecs": [
                    "H_264_42",
                    "H_264_41"
                ]
            }
        },
        "Extensions": {
            "available": {
                "aplext:backstack:10": {}
            }
        },
        "System": {
            "application": {
                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.c1ed78ba-9003-4904-9376-b9a05b3a4bcc"
            },
            "user": {
                "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AH7FLOU7DBFRWVIENTV7VT7EMQLPAGYMFU4YUTI6OSBCK6GOKXWNQ6BI3BPZPEMN2TQFXGZCO43KXB3HJNVJPBJILPEDLGIAMQK2DK3C42S5FBPCQSN6B46FMQDATFSCL42YCF25PR5CFPGHYUFIDIJHZAJRIGMZ5BGZMU7FNJB4I6KBVDF5N2WIXCIG6YMV2X4ZO3QETGA23HQ"
            },
            "device": {
                "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AGZ65ZMWRSISWS4RB63ZEBKJDJPMICI5WU6SDYTU7CZKDFASRAAR7WNYRTVKYWRURCC77E2EIGXBBUTO3REKDGWMLJDN7ODAHKWJLJCTNHN3CU3LVXDMGRJJ3HIXMWRLVT6D5OFWNYXZ73J7Y6TCONRXYL2OTJHRQ7SUGQKEBBIPNVIYZ35WI",
                "supportedInterfaces": {}
            },
            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
            "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.X2fY3XTWW8zRZtwE6km2AIaSnhaAfSLKYqzgwlZrui6OyCS03Lfh1dJWHg4sZxTZqWyssV7VFWErW-gTZFUdkagtbbknuZQ3qlVQlwpZPaKhKBYC9VBDfmnGtjjDDCAAUyvB8ZIInbuxsrZ6DwYtuj5sa5_wGSfc0s2THQqP9Azklgk5UobwMN0iWsrhDSXy4guB4KaEJscD8_OLr2ZnbvWqy3tAPv3zfEsb8OmnOC7FBMHHgN-aCIRubnZNu8YA2Xtf-usOn1wVAjaIwEdlfgrOCRfFpZc3l7tfHTfX9HfLerRFh_IWQWc61DVfQZhyH4yeH5fdKUVDMels4zXlKQ"
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.e6d2bca6-4680-4367-8bb1-104e038c35ba",
        "timestamp": "2021-12-03T02:22:58Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my current code, hopefully someone can help me

Comment: You're missing the code that handles the intents. That would be useful. Also check your error logs if you can

Comment: I've already solved this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of researching and github searches, this is the github repo you need to look at if you are willing to host your skill locally using REST API

https://github.com/hanstxu/alexa_endpoint_js